# System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The item tcm: does not exist

Tags: 2011, core-service

I am using Tridion core service to delete failed publish transactions and reschedule them. But I am get the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[ABC.CoreServiceReference.CoreServiceFault]:
>   The item tcm:0-31371-66560 does not exist.

This is happening in every method I have created whenever I am trying to access any Tridion Item.

Code snippet:

To Create the Connection I am using the following code:

```
private bool CreateCoreServiceClientInstance()
    {
        try
        {
           m_serverBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[CommonConstants.CmsServerBaseURL];
            //m_serverBaseUrl = (string)serverConfSection["serverBaseURL"];
            if (m_serverBaseUrl == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error in getting serverBaseURL from the web.config");
            }

             var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding
            {
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
                ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
                {
                    MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647,
                    MaxArrayLength = 2147483647
                }
            };

            //Core service connection through TCP binding

             var remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://" + m_serverBaseUrl + 
                                                     ":2660/CoreService/netTcp_2010");
             m_objChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService2010>
                                                     (netTcpBinding, remoteAddress);
             m_coreServiceInstance = m_objChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
             m_coreServiceInstance.Impersonate(UserId);             

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CloseCoreServiceClientInstance();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Code I am using with the client to delete the transaction:

```
public Boolean DeleteTransaction(string transactionId)
    {
        Boolean result = false;
        try
        {
            UtilityHelper.LogInTextFile("Client Creation Started");
            CreateCoreServiceClientInstance();
            UtilityHelper.LogInTextFile("Client Created Started");
            m_coreServiceInstance.Delete(transactionId);
            UtilityHelper.LogInTextFile(transactionId + " Deleted");
            CloseCoreServiceClientInstance();
            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            UtilityHelper.LogInTextFile(exc.ToString());
            CloseCoreServiceClientInstance();         
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `tcm:0-31371-66560` exists in the Tridion instance the CoreService is trying to connect.

Comment: It's not happening only for this. I am getting same exception even when I am scheduling the publish for a page tcm:22-7550-64

Comment: What I meant to validate is that the `m_serverBaseUrl` that you are using is the right one, where your data is, it so often happens that we keep connecting to a different instance.

Comment: I have installed my application as windows service on CMS server. And the instance is pointing to localhost only

Comment: Thanks Likhan. You directed me in to right direction. The serverbaseurl was the issue.

Comment: Great to hear it's solved! Maybe Likhan can add it as an answer and you can accept it? That way other people experiencing a similar problem will see the solution immediately instead of having to sort through the comments :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please validate that the `m_serverBaseUrl` that you are using is the right one, where your data is, it so often happens that we keep connecting to a different instance.